# Override field_multiple_value_form function

Tags: 7, entities

I want to override `field_multiple_value_form` function not the `theme_field_multiple_value_form` function.

How will I do this. I want to execute my own custom function instead of executing `field_multiple_value_form` function.

Comment: That's not easy (maybe not even strictly possible without altering core). Perhaps if you explained what you need to accomplish it would be easier to suggest an alternative

Comment: I want to alter the `$form_state['field']['field_name']['und']['items_count'] `value and the `$max` variable value after the switch statement.